Define different class method depending on whether an input parameter is present/absent
I would like to be able to define a different class method, depending on whether one of the inputs is present or not. Something like:
class mcmc(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y=None):
        if Y is None:
            def input_vector(self, beta):
                return beta.dot(X)
        else:
            def input_vector(self, beta):
                return beta.dot(np.vstack([X, Y]))

I could have coded this directly in the method, like:
class mcmc(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y=None):
        self.X = X
        if Y is not None:
            self.Y = Y

    def input_vector(self, beta):
        if self.__hasattr__('Y'):
            return return beta.dot(np.vstack([self.X, self.Y]))
        else:
            return beta.dot(self.X)

but the function is used repeatedly (millions of times), so it probably adds a lot to the execution time.
Another similar possibility, inspired by How can I call any method inside a class depending on an input to another method in the same class?, is probably:
class mcmc(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y=None):
        self.X = X
        if Y is not None:
            self.Y = Y
            self.method = 'input_vector_XY'
        else:
            self.method = 'input_vector_X'

    def input_vector(self, beta):
        return self.__getattribute__(self.method)(beta)

    def input_vector_XY(self, beta):
        return return beta.dot(np.vstack([self.X, self.Y]))
    
    def input_vector_X(self, beta):
        return beta.dot(self.X)

This also involves an "overhead" in terms of calling an additional function.

This looks like premature optimization. if self.Y is not None is unlikely to be a bottleneck. If this method is called repeatedly on the same instance, caching np.vstack([self.X, self.Y]) would probably provide more speedup, and could also eliminate the branch. If this method isn't called repeatedly on the same instance, the extra work you want to put in __init__ is likely to be more than any work you save in input_vector.

@user2357112 you mean that the first version of the code would literally work? - Can I define methods within the __init__ ?(I haven't tried it, just posted as an example of what I want to do.)

Why not setting Y to a vector of ones by default and doing always the dot product? If Y exists then you have dot(X,Y). If Y does not exist then you have dot(X,1) which is X

@Cincinnatus: dot doesn't work like that, and also I think you might have missed the vstack.

Instead of 1 use a vector of ones. The key is using a default value that is neutral to the operations performed, so the result is X when you apply the default value

@RogerV.: No, the first version wouldn't literally work. I mean you should just go with the straightforward implementation, putting if self.Y is not None: ... else: ... inside input_vector, and if you really need to optimize, you should figure out what's really taking all the time and optimize that.

@Cincinnatus it is true in the example above - I could set $Y$ to zero. In my actual code $\beta$ would contain extra parameter(s) if Y is present, which would need to be optimizes.

@user2357112 good point, thanks.

Well, if you need to do two very different things based on a condition that what conditionals are for. Use an if to check if Y exists or not.

You said "probably adds a lot to the execution time" - have you actually measured it? An overhead of a single if statement is likely to be negligible compared to the actual function being called, i.e. you're probably looking at a difference of 10s vs 10.001s. If that really matters you shouldn't be using Python anyway.

In order to avoid making the decision each time input_vector is called, instead of doing this on the instance level you could do it on the class level by defining two different classes (maybe with a common base class to avoid duplicating features), and make mcmc a factory function which returns an instance of one or the other class:
def mcmc(X, Y=None):
    if Y is None:
        return MCMCWithoutY(X)
    else:
        return MCMCWithY(X, Y)


class BaseMCMC:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X

    def common_features(args):
        # do something

    def input_vector(self, beta):
        # must be implemented in derived classes
        # alternatively, provide a default implementation
        raise NotImplementedError


class MCMCWithoutY(BaseMCMC):
    def input_vector(self, beta):
        return beta.dot(self.X)


class MCMCWithY(BaseMCMC):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        super().__init__(X)
        self.Y = Y

    def input_vector(self, beta):
        return beta.dot(np.vstack([self.X, self.Y]))


Thanks. There are also other class methods, which are the same, regardless of whether Y is present, and which I would not want to duplicate. Right now I am literally using two different classes with many identical methods.

Nice, but I'd only use 2 classes: BaseMCMC with the input_vector method from MCMCWithoutY, and MCMCwithY

The solution that you already mentioned in your question can be improved a bit, and after that your requirements should be satisfied
class mcmc(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y=None):
        self.X = X
        self.input_vector = self.input_vector_X
        if Y is not None:
            self.Y = Y
            self.input_vector = self.input_vector_XY

    def input_vector_XY(self, beta):
        return beta.dot(np.vstack([self.X, self.Y]))
    
    def input_vector_X(self, beta):
        return beta.dot(self.X)
        
m = mcmc(X=X, Y=None)
m.input_vector(beta)

The downside, is that you won't receive help from IDE about self.input_vector, or automatic documentation generation, because it is not true method of the class defined by def. It's just a variable containing reference to the method
